# How to optimize loops in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

```
for y in df['DayHrStoreKey'].unique():
    tempcor=df[df['DayHrStoreKey']==y][['Unique Visits','Orders Delivered']].corr()['Unique Visits'][1]
    for i in df[df['DayHrStoreKey']==y].index:
        df.loc[i,'Correlation']=tempcor
```

I'm trying to find the correlation between two variables for a set of rows from a dataframe based on a DayHrStoreKey. The dataframe has 335592 rows and there are 39648 unique DayHrStoreKey keys. This seems to be running for a long time and I'm wondering if there's anything else I can implement in my code to speed things up

This has been running for over 20 mins without any results and I'd like to know if there are any libraries that I can leverage to run this faster or if I should rewrite the code in a different way. Any creative ways to use numpy to make this faster?

Comment: `groupby` and `corr` each group

Comment: This is not a really directly helpful answer, hence it's a comment. Pandas is really slow unless used completely correctly and probably rewriting everything to native numpy will lead to a lot of improvement

Comment: Just use native Pandas methodes instead of `for`-loops (no need to rewrite anything in NumPy). And please, take the full [tour] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Timus in the comments, you want to avoid using loops and use the vectorized functions provided by pandas itself. Using groupby and apply work well here. I think there might be a faster way using groupby.transform but I haven't figured that one out.

```
corr = df.groupby("DayHrStoreKey")[["Unique Visits", "Orders Delivered"]].apply(lambda x: x.corr()["Unique Visits"][1])
corr.name = 'correlation'
df = df.merge(corr, left_on = 'DayHrStoreKey', right_index = True)
```